# Error ASP.NET Core EF Core and SQL Server 2005: The version of SQL Server in use does not support datatype 'datetime2'

Tags: entity-framework, sql-server-2005, entity-framework-6, asp.net-core-mvc

I receive the following exception when attempting to update a database record even though I was passing in the correct datetime values to the controller.

*System.ArgumentException: The version of SQL Server in use does not support datatype 'datetime2'*

Other stackoverflow topics suggest either the datetime has not been set or to edit the edmx file, which in this case, doesn't exist. I have tested the application with a localdb context in Visual Studio 2015 but I only receive an error when trying to connect to the SQL Server 2005 DbContext.

Is this exception due to an incompatibility with SQL Server 2005 or is there a workaround which I'm missing?

#### Controllers/SecureController/Save

```
public ActionResult save([FromForm]SubscriptionsViewModel newSubscription)   
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        var mySubscription = Mapper.Map<Subscription>(newSubscription);

        _context.Entry(mySubscription).State = EntityState.Modified;

        _context.SaveChanges();
        _logger.LogInformation("saving to database");
        return RedirectToAction("subscription", "secure");
    }
    return RedirectToAction("index", "secure");
}
```

#### ViewModels/SubscriptionsViewModel.cs

```
 using System;
    using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
    using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;    
    namespace XX.ViewModels
    {
        public class SubscriptionsViewModel
        {
            public int SubscriptionRef { get; set; }
            public int MemberID { get; set; }
            public string SubTypeID { get; set; }
            public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
            public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }
            public byte PrimaryPaysInd { get; set; }

            [NotMapped]
            [StringLength(15, MinimumLength = 4)]
            public string searchParam { get; set; }

            public SubscriptionsViewModel()
            {
            }

            [NotMapped]
            public bool PrimaryPaysIndBool
            {
                    get { return PrimaryPaysInd > 0; }
            set { PrimaryPaysInd = value ? Convert.ToByte(1) : Convert.ToByte(0); }
            }
        }
    }
```

#### Models/Subscription.cs

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace XX.Models
{
    public class Subscription
    {
        [Key]
        public int SubscriptionRef { get; set; }
        public int MemberID { get; set; }
        public string SubTypeID { get; set; }
        public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
        public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }
        public byte PrimaryPaysInd { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: The datatype `datetime2`is not in SQL Server 2005. It's 2008 and up

Comment: I haven't specified `datetime2` in my `SubscriptionsViewModel` class; only `datetime`.

Comment: is this code first?

Comment: Yes, albeit, without migrations.

Comment: can you put `SubscriptionsViewModel` code also?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

EF Core does not support SQL Server 2005, but 2012 and forward

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/providers/sql-server/

Comment: as the link ErikEJ provided now redirects to the main EF documentation. You can find the direct link here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/providers/sql-server/


> "Supported Database Engines
Microsoft SQL Server (2008 onwards)"

Comment: As of today, the documentation says "Supported Database Engines Microsoft SQL Server (**2012 onwards**)"